# Spliting subspaces and finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields, primitive-roots

I'm sure that the following is true, but I can't prove it.

Let $R<S<K, R=\mathrm{GF}(q),\  S= \mathrm{GF}(q^n), \ K= \mathrm{GF}(q^{mn})$ be a tower of finite fields and
$A = \{\theta\in K: \operatorname{ord}\theta = q^{mn}-1\}$ be the set of primitive elements. I want to prove the following statement. If $_RW$ is a subspace of $_RK$, $\dim_RW = n$  such that **for every** $\theta \in A$
$$
W\oplus W\theta\oplus\cdots\oplus W\theta^{m-1} = K,
$$
then $W = bS$ for some $b\in K$.

I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: $q$ is a cardinality of $R$. $q = p^t$, where $p$ is a prime and $t\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: No need for $W$ to be a subring. After all, for any non-zero $b\in K$ the space $bS$ satisfies the requirements. But, it is easy to show that the set
$$L=\{\alpha\in K\mid W\alpha\subseteq W\}$$ is a field. I just don't see right away why we should have $L=S$. A cool question!

Comment: Also I want to note that there are a lot of subspaces $W\neq bS$ such that the previous decomposition is valid for **one** primitive element $\theta\in A$.

Comment: Crossposted to [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/230767/15503). The usual comment: Please crosslink as a matter of course.